# iOS - display a view for few seconds and change view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm designing a app where it first shows a terms and conditions view and then on accepting it, it moves on to next view where I've used a UIImage to add a background image, so that I could display a welcome image for my app and then after 5 seconds I have changed the view to user login. I've used the view based application template without storyboards and I've also enabled ARC.

I've used the following codes:

Accepting Terms and Condition [accept.h, accept.m, accept.xib]:

```
- (IBAction)AcceptPractTandC:(id)sender
{
    PractionerImage *PracImage = [[PractionerImage alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:PracImage animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Displaying Image for 5 Seconds and showing next view [PractionerImage.h, PractionerImage.m, PractionerImage.xib]:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    count = 0;
    PracImage = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/1.0) target:self selector:@selector(PracImageSkip) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)PracImageSkip
{
    count += 1;
    if (count > 5) {
        ViewController *Intro = [[ViewController alloc]init];
        [self presentViewController:Intro animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

and I have the user details in the files ViewController.m, ViewController.h, ViewController.xib.

Comment: Why don't you use whitespaces and newlines properly? I hope this is just a copy-paste error, but if your real, actual code looks like this, then you should read and follow some kind of coding style-standard because what I saw here is **ugly.**

Comment: You haven't asked a question. I'm guessing something doesn't work here, but what? What goes wrong?

Comment: You're using the timer in a very strange way. There's no need for a repeating timer to do what you're doing. Make it non-repeating with a time interval of 5 seconds (or use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: instead).

Comment: I was able to get the expected output but, i get a warning 

Warning: Attempt to present <ViewController: 0x7107ce0> on <PractionerImage: 0x757d4a0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!